# Make docker accessible in LAN

Tags: docker

Somehow containers_id have changed, and I have no idea of how can I add a container to this bridge to make a project running in docker available to our LAN.

Here are my running containers:
[image]

And here is my network ls:
[image]

I'm reading all this tuto's but afraid to mess up things, can someone help me to make this project available for example, in 192.168.0.10?

**[UPDATE1]: the output of netstat -tulpn**

```
netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
udp        0      0 172.18.0.1:123          0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 192.168.0.10:123        0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:123           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4400            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:49884           0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           -                   
udp6       0      0 :::14324                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::34cc:82ff:fec:123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::5036:49ff:fec:123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::8029:1ff:fe0e:123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::1892:d2ff:fe0:123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::42:d1ff:fed3::123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 2804:14d:c680:1b71::123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 2804:14d:c680:1b71::123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::86c2:2e62:9e5:123 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 ::1:123                 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 fe80::86c2:2e62:9e5:546 :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::58147                :::*                                -                   
udp6       0      0 :::5353                 :::*
```

**UPDATE2: docker inspect on docker_agil1_1**

```
sudo docker inspect --format '{{json .NetworkSettings}}' docker_agil1_1
{"Bridge":"","SandboxID":"b37a7a73bf05cb215796a8b5c34ca9a1c9c2f332f3e865f974980ac5fd034bf2","HairpinMode":false,"LinkLocalIPv6Address":"","LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"Ports":{"443/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"443"}],"80/tcp":[{"HostIp":"0.0.0.0","HostPort":"80"}]},"SandboxKey":"/var/run/docker/netns/b37a7a73bf05","SecondaryIPAddresses":null,"SecondaryIPv6Addresses":null,"EndpointID":"","Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"IPAddress":"","IPPrefixLen":0,"IPv6Gateway":"","MacAddress":"","Networks":{"docker_default":{"IPAMConfig":null,"Links":["docker_agil1_db_1:agil1_db_1","docker_agil1_db_1:docker_agil1_db_1","docker_agil1_db_1:mysql"],"Aliases":["e1b469ab4d66","agil1"],"NetworkID":"2889780f55a072444137855fb6c94c4df53d62f0ec51d5b09d42ec8e8d0eb372","EndpointID":"59bb683bd3a81c620492ed7ddea811d7919bbaa08a738249b6ec60e6f50f5043","Gateway":"172.18.0.1","IPAddress":"172.18.0.3","IPPrefixLen":16,"IPv6Gateway":"","GlobalIPv6Address":"","GlobalIPv6PrefixLen":0,"MacAddress":"02:42:ac:12:00:03","DriverOpts":null}}}
```

**Update3:**
docker network inspect docker_default:

```
 [
    {
        "Name": "docker_default",
        "Id": "2889780f55a072444137855fb6c94c4df53d62f0ec51d5b09d42ec8e8d0eb372",
        "Created": "2017-08-24T12:00:28.615469234-03:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "17753e89370d03571efe42994b9e1b7300787d05132b6577721792eb1c68446a": {
                "Name": "docker_agilapi_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "5766d902a9447147a583795eafc23175509ee2696a001419b7fa1c9a3881ed74",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "991880fa4093461f902fae7239cfe138f25eacc152687d673e109bbd0cee2f56": {
                "Name": "docker_agil1_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "61b2d06c62a821a25e44a85042509ecd7d58d8dbd4228b60372d181d48b6a55e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "a75bbb07436930652c2024bee20b426c1d67e95472ee4f635da57fd8370f8431": {
                "Name": "docker_agilapi_1",
                "EndpointID": "51fb0cdb402cd0a9aec9c97accd4028140d92509923d3023bd652a2de5d2d203",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "e1b469ab4d663e2575232bfee06ef52d01c0178946e3e174b64ba2d316a3051d": {
                "Name": "docker_agil1_1",
                "EndpointID": "59bb683bd3a81c620492ed7ddea811d7919bbaa08a738249b6ec60e6f50f5043",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

sudo brctl show:

```
 bridge name    bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
 br-2889780f55a0        8000.0242d1d3851d   no      veth081c0e3
                            veth342b2da
                            veth34fb985
                            vethe0daeb5 docker0     8000.02427e7776a8   no
```

Ifconfig -a:

```
 br-2889780f55a0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 172.18.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
         inet6 fe80::42:d1ff:fed3:851d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 02:42:d1:d3:85:1d  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 43  bytes 1468 (1.4 KiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 78  bytes 6534 (6.3 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
         ether 02:42:7e:77:76:a8  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet 192.168.0.10  netmask 255.252.0.0  broadcast 192.171.255.255
         inet6 2804:14d:c680:1b71::6  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
         inet6 2804:14d:c680:1b71:1611:48cb:a555:faea  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
         inet6 fe80::86c2:2e62:9e56:6694  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 00:22:15:bd:5d:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 5356  bytes 519236 (507.0 KiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 2461  bytes 313106 (305.7 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 2  collisions 0
         device memory 0xdffc0000-e0000000  

 lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
         inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
         inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
         loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 veth081c0e3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet6 fe80::34cc:82ff:fec3:7982  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 36:cc:82:c3:79:82  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 36  bytes 3418 (3.3 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 veth342b2da: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet6 fe80::1892:d2ff:fe0d:f80b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 1a:92:d2:0d:f8:0b  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 38  bytes 3638 (3.5 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 veth34fb985: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet6 fe80::8029:1ff:fe0e:bdba  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 82:29:01:0e:bd:ba  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 30  bytes 1440 (1.4 KiB)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 57  bytes 4452 (4.3 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

 vethe0daeb5: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
         inet6 fe80::5036:49ff:fec6:e6b1  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
         ether 52:36:49:c6:e6:b1  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
         RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
         RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
         TX packets 35  bytes 3348 (3.2 KiB)
         TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

iptables --list

```
 Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
 destination         

 Chain FORWARD (policy DROP) target     prot opt source              
 destination          DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere            
 anywhere             DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere            
 anywhere             ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
 ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED DOCKER     all  --  anywhere            
 anywhere             ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
 ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ACCEPT  
 all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate
 RELATED,ESTABLISHED DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere 
 ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ACCEPT  
 all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

 Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT) target     prot opt source              
 destination         

 Chain DOCKER (2 references) target     prot opt source              
 destination          
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.2           tcp dpt:mysql
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:https
 ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             172.18.0.3           tcp dpt:http

 Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references) target     prot opt source      
 destination          DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
 DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             RETURN  
 all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

 Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references) target     prot opt source           
 destination          RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

**Update4: docker exec**

```
 > sudo docker exec e1b469ab4d66 bash -c "tail -f /var/log/httpd/*"
 ==> /var/log/httpd/access.log <==

 ==> /var/log/httpd/access_log <==

 ==> /var/log/httpd/error.log <== [Mon Oct 02 17:22:32.987017 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 17] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for
 172.18.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Mon Oct 02 17:22:33.073314 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 17] AH01909: RSA
 certificate configured for 172.18.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which
 matches the server name

 ==> /var/log/httpd/error_log <== [Mon Oct 02 17:22:32.983193 2017] [suexec:notice] [pid 17] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper:
 /usr/sbin/suexec) [Mon Oct 02 17:22:33.068405 2017] [core:warn] [pid
 17] AH00117: Ignoring deprecated use of DefaultType in line 99 of
 /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably
 determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.18.0.3.
 Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message [Mon
 Oct 02 17:22:33.070143 2017] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 17] AH01757:
 generating secret for digest authentication ... [Mon Oct 02
 17:22:33.071655 2017] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 17] AH02282: No
 slotmem from mod_heartmonitor [Mon Oct 02 17:22:33.072342 2017]
 [ssl:warn] [pid 17] AH01873: Init: Session Cache is not configured
 [hint: SSLSessionCache] [Mon Oct 02 17:22:34.107773 2017]
 [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 17] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips PHP/7.0.22 configured -- resuming normal
 operations [Mon Oct 02 17:22:34.109284 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17]
 AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Comment: Sorry about the many docker inspects, but can I get a `docker network inspect docker_default`, a `brctl show`, an `ifconfig -a` and a `iptables --list`? It just doesn't make sense to me why your containers ports aren't getting forwarded

Comment: Sure samprog, question updated . I don't know if heaven exist's, but if it does, you already got a seat somewhere over there.

Comment: lmao I wouldn't praise the day before the evening, my friend, we still don't have a solution. I've checked your update and I still have no idea why your connection is getting refused. All outputs look alright, except for `netstat -tulpn` (which shows your open ports). Can you see if `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` is set to 1? If yes, let's try something trivial: have you tried turning it off and back on again? First the containers (`docker restart [ContainerName]`) and if that doesn't work the host?

Comment: Yes, it is 1 and no, it doesn't work restarting.

Comment: So I just googled a bit around, trying to find why netstat is showing IPv6 ports instead of IPv4 ports. Turns out this is okay, as AF_INET6 sockets actually work for both IPv4 and IPv6 (you learn something everyday lol). So your containers are all setup correctly. Now either your application inside the container is not ready to receive traffic on the given ports or you're trying to access the application wrong. Other than that, I really am out of ideas, I'm sorry

Comment: Wait a second! I'm using docker exec to catch some error, I'll update once again, can you check it out? There's something weird.

Comment: The error log says the SSL-certificate doesn't include the correct ServerName. Sadly I have close to no experience with httpd. What you could do is recreate the container with the `--net=host` flag and then add the application network with `docker network connect docker_default [ContainerName]`, but you don't seem to have the `docker run` command to create the container. Also I don't know if it's possible to connect to a bridge network when you've created the container in the host network. I recommend you to create a new question with the current problem. Hopefully it will be resolved soon!

Comment: The current problem being: "RSA certificate configured for 172.18.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name" and the problem includes httpd in a docker container. Also You might want to check out the date on your server since the error log portrays october 2nd lol

Comment: I finally have physical access to the machine and even trying to run "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" won't work. It throw's "ERR_SOCKET_NOT_CONNECTED".

Answer (score 0):

So currently all you can access from your LAN is `docker_agil_1` on port 80 and 443 and your `docker_agil1_db_1` on port 3306. Of course all on the ip of your docker-host.

To make a container available from outside, you need to start the container with the `-p [HostPort]:[ContainerPort]` flag, as you've done with the before-mentioned containers.

The containers are automatically added to the "bridge" network. If you'd like to change that, either use `docker network connect` to connect a container to an additional network or use the `--net [Network]` flag when starting a container.

Helpful [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports) about -p

Helpful [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) about --net

Helpful [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network/) about docker network (the command)

Helpful [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) about docker networking in general

Comment: Yes but when I type the LAN adress (192.168.0.10) it says "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". No firewall running, docker ps show all containers started. This is the same ip we used to access. Any tip?

Comment: What's your output of `netstat  -tulpn`?

Comment: Seems like your host is listening to ports 80 and 443 on IPv6 but not IPv4, neither is port 3306 visible. Are your containers really running or are they restarting every few seconds? Also do you have the `docker run` command with which you started the containers?

Comment: samprog thank's for your efford, so, my start comand is basically: 
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo docker start docker_agil1_db_1 docker_agil1_1
sudo docker start docker_agilapi_db_1 docker_agilapi_1

This machine has no monitor, keyboard or mouse. She's locked up, I connect trough SSH and SFTP (wich is working fine).

Comment: No worries, I'm trying my best lol. Do you have the explicit `docker run` command which created the containers? If not, can you attach the output of `docker inspect --format '{{json .NetworkSettings}}' docker_agil_1`?

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the containername: `docker inspect --format '{{json .NetworkSettings}}' docker_agil1_1`. The containernames are very unlikely to have changed, and the ids don't matter if they change

Answer (score 0):

The solution was:
1- Stop and delete all docker containers;
2- sudo docker-compose up -d on both docker folders;

Of course, I lost all databases inside docker container_db but it was so much better than spent almoust 4 hour's trying to find a solution, because it can be easily recovered with the sql dump file.

Special thank's to everyone that helped.Thank you for you efford.